# Packages lucidabr and yhmath results in wrong symbols

Tags: math-mode, fonts, yhmath, lucida

I obtained the TUG `lucida` fonts and used them just for testing in one of my documents which loaded `yhmath` too.

In this document, the `$\Delta x$` is used quite a lot and after looking about the results, I realized the behaviour produced by the minimal example below too:

[image]

The `\Delta` character is displayed as a huge `\sqrt`, the `\Gamma` symbol as well, the `\Omega` symbol becomes a `\widehat` accent.

Changing the order of loading (`yhmath` first, then `lucidabr`) will cure the problem, but this not an option for someone that uses packages that load `yhmath` and `lucidabr` in the some wrong order etc.

My question is more of general nature: Can this wrong mapping be solved? I personally don't need `yhmath` actually (it was loaded just by accident)

One option of course is to switch to the standard or other math fonts that do not conflict with `yhmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Can be omitted, shows the same effect with or without using this
\usepackage{lucidabr} 
\usepackage{yhmath}

\begin{document}

\[\Delta x \]

\[\Gamma x \]

\[ \Omega  x\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: the solution to every font having its own encoding is for all fonts to use unicode. one day....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The likelihood to have first contact with extraterrestials is larger than to have the unicode scheme one day in near future :-P

Comment: I have no problem if I use `lucimatx.sty` instead of `lucidabr`.

Comment: @egreg: `lucimatx`? I don't have this package -- it wasn't in the TUG zip files and seems not to be part of `TL`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `lucimatx` should be included in the distribution of the Lucida Type1 fonts.

Comment: @egreg: No, I don't find it -- neither as a direct file in the `.zip` file nor as being generated after running `pdflatex lucidabr.ins`. There's `lucbmath.sty`, however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to load `lucidabr` with the `expert` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[expert]{lucidabr}
\usepackage{yhmath}

\begin{document}

\[\Delta x \]

\[\Gamma x \]

\[ \Omega  x\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise, the definition of `\Delta` is

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathord}{largesymbols}{'321}
```

which is clearly wrong when `yhmath` is also loaded.